# Where is my application on target computer when deployed via clickonce?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I have an application which runs on my system inside and outside VS. So there is nothing missing from my computer that needs by my application. But when I use clickonce to publish it and then use clickonce to install it on my PC, the application crashes after start.

I am trying to find why this is happening but I can not find the copy that clickonce installed on my system.

I checked c:\program files and c:\program files (x86), but I can not find it. Where Clickonce install my application on target computer?

My application is a c#/wpf application.

Is there any better way than click once to publish software over internet and update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following page: http://blog.allanglen.com/2010/01/clickonce-installation-location.

Windows XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\{username}\Local Settings\Apps

Windows Vista/Windows 7:
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps

Personally I have never liked Clickonce for production programs; I always seem to get applications not updating properly, or some other funkyness.  I generally use either the Windows Installer project in VS2010 and earlier and InstallShield Limited for VS2012.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any freely available tools to create upgradeable installer so it upgrade the application over internet?

Comment: About that I don't know.  I do know that you can setup the InstallShield installer to "Update" an installation of your program (which essentially uninstalls and re-installs without the user needing to go into control panel).  You could relatively easily have some code that, on startup, checks a webservice or something for a new version, and can download it, and start it up.  I havent done that myself, but conceptually it doesn's seem like it would be too hard.